# How to generate Duplo instructions?

Tags: instructions, duplo, cad

I am aware of how to create a Lego model and generate instructions using LDD and Stud.io

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this for Duplo. How does one do this?

EDIT:
@alex yes I think my question was poorly phrased.

I think my real question is "how can I create a Duplo model in LDD or Stud.io"

Comment: https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/173785-duplo-for-studio/ might get you closer to what you're trying for.

Comment: Could you specify if the problem is with finding Duplo elements? Or, perhaps, you have your Duplo model assembled but have trouble generating instructions? Or both?

Comment: My problem with LDD and Stud.io was with finding Duplo parts. According to your answer below stud.io should already have Duplo parts? Although judging by the forum link posted by @chicks they need to be imported first.

Answer (score 4):

I can see some Duplo bricks in LDraw parts library, which is used by Stud.io as well, so you should be able to work out instructions the same way you do with usual bricks.

One thing to note is that availability of Duplo parts in LDraw is rather limited.

Alternatively, you can use LDCad (which uses LDraw library) to create your model. In this case you can find most of the Duplo elements under **Library sorted by function > Duplo**.

Comment: You can import LDraw parts into Stud.io, and probably into LDD as well, but LDD it is no longer supported and I don't have it installed so I can't check.

Comment: I couldn't find any Duplo bricks in Stud.io.  Are you sure they're in there?  Could you add how to find them?

Comment: @chicks now that you've asked I had another look at the question and asked to clarify exact issue here.

Comment: When in stud.io and search for "Duplo" in  "BL Categories" and "Shapes" I don't see any results. Should I assume I have to import the Duplo parts first, or should they already be present?